# Ubuntu 12.04: screen freezes when I open the laptop

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, tty

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my lenovo G580 laptop.
When I close the laptop (goes into hyvernation mode) and open it, sometimes my screen freezes (I can still see my mouse moving, but that is all).
I suspect something went wrong about x, or unity or something, but that's my best clue.

I can still access other tty, so I would like to know how to diagnose this situation using tty.